# When indexing switch to manual permanent redirect for url not working - Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Facing a weird issue, when indexing turn off the Magento permanent URL redirection  not working for products and categories.

Has anyone face this issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you use other custom redirects in your .htaccess?

Comment: @MaxBongiorno  No, I didn't use any custom redirection. It isn't practical to write custom redirect in .htaccess as our catalog is huge more than 20k